# Error installing Google Cloud SDK in ubuntu via curl

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, installation, google-cloud-platform

### running the command:

```
curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash
```

(I try "curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com/ | bash" have same error)

No problem...

• Installing: App Engine SDK for Python and PHP ... Done
• Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool ... Done
• Installing: BigQuery Command Line  Tool (Platform Specific) ... Done
• Installing: Cloud DNS Admin Command Line Interface ... Done
• Installing: Cloud SDK Core Command Line Tools  ... Done
• Installing: Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Specific) ... Done
• Installing: Cloud SDK for Python and PHP Developers ... Done
• Installing: Cloud SQL Admin Command Line Interface ... Done 
• Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool ... Done
• Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) ... Done 
• Installing: Compute Engine Command Line Interface (RC) ... Done 
• Installing: Compute Engine Command Line Tool ... Done
• Installing: Compute Engine Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) ... Done

the error:

```
Installing: gcloud app Python Extensions ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 367, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 346, in main
    pargs.additional_components)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 309, in Install
    components = InstallComponents(to_install)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 331, in InstallComponents
    components.update(component_ids=component_ids, allow_no_backup=True)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 235, in __call__
    post_run_hooks=None, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 878, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/update.py", line 65, in Run
    args.component_ids, allow_no_backup=args.allow_no_backup)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 457, in Update
    self._InstallFunction(staging_state, diff))
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 372, in _UpdateAndPrint
    action_func(component.id)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 378, in Inner
    return install_state.Install(diff.latest, component_id)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/local_state.py", line 80, in _TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/local_state.py", line 418, in Install
    files = self._GetInstaller(snapshot).Install(component_id)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 109, in Install
    return self._InstallTar(component)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 144, in _InstallTar
    url, self.__download_directory, self.__sdk_root)
  File "/home/fernandmg/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 176, in DownloadAndExtractTar
    shutil.copyfileobj(req, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 49, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 567, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

obviously the error is in "gcloud app Python Extensions" ....

details:

Python version is 2.7.6
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

### what I can do? possible solution, help?

Answer (score 0):

problems you probably met:

1. you're under a network environment which will interrupt SSL connection, few firewall will cause that. Switch to different network environment and try again (Maybe your mobile network?)
2. your Python installation is not complete, SSL module may not work, try use aptitude install a different copy of Python 2, and try again (remember to specify Python interpreter to the newly installed one)

The information is too few, I will try to do some exp to reproduce your situation.

Hope it helps.

**Updated**

I saw some TLS issues happened on Ubuntu 14.04 which will interrupt SSL connections, that might be the problem, is Ubuntu 14.04 your only solution?

If then, you might need these info to fix the problem:

[SSL handshake is not working when compiled in Ubuntu 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417562/ssl-handshake-is-not-working-when-compiled-in-ubuntu-14)